# How to check in .git directory in a sub directory of my git repo?

Tags: git

I have a git repo that contains a grunt task that uses Bower to check out and arrange code from other git repos. For testing purposes, I would like to have several sources in a fixtures directory. Something like:

```
/test
    /fixtures
        /foo-project
            .git/
            foo.js
            bower.json
        /bar-project
            .git/
            bar.js
            bower.json
```

In order to version the fixtures alongside the tests, I would like to check in the `.git` directories under fixtures. (I know this is an odd thing to do, but I can't find a better way.) However, I don't know how to make git check in `.git` files. Is it possible?

Another thought I had was checking in the files in a directory named `git` and renaming it to `.git` at runtime, but that's sorta hacky.

I read about submodules, but it looks like those have to be external git repos, and I'd really rather version the fixtures along with the tests.

Comment: I suppose you can't use submodules?

Comment: Almost certainly there is a better way. What about submodules? Why don't they work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my answer applies to you, I had the same problem, but while using buildout for building and deploying my django project.

I found out that this buildout extension was very helpfull for avoiding the hell of git submodules:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gp.vcsdevelop/2.2.3

If you want to see my implementaion, see this answer: [Do you version control the invidual apps or the whole project or both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967817/do-you-version-control-the-invidual-apps-or-the-whole-project-or-both/18429335#18429335)

If you want to know more about git submodules (ignoring my warning :-) ), somebody gave a very clear explanation in this answer: [Tracking 3rd party code with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677393/tracking-3rd-party-code-with-git/18453027#18453027)